# Anime about a gifted blond girl joining a department that hunts monsters

Tags: story-identification, anime

This anime may be from the 90's. It's about a shy blond girl joining a team that specializes in hunting demons, vampires, monsters, sorcerers, etc. They use greenish glowing crystals as bullets. It's themed in a dark city with mostly black clothes.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/58193) and see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, more details about the plot or specific scenes you remember can help identify this.

Comment: My immediate thought is *Hellsing* - I've never seen it, but from what I know about it, it matches everything except the glowing crystal bullets (and possibly the time period).

Answer (score 1):

Could you be searching for [Witch Hunter Robin](https://myanimelist.net/anime/7/Witch_Hunter_Robin)?

> Robin Sena is a "craft user", born in Japan and raised by the Roman Catholic Church in Italy. She is trained to use her craft of fire to hunt down witches. Witchcraft is a genetic trait, dormant within a number of individuals within the human population. Powers can be "awakened" in these dormant human "seeds" at any time, which seems to also drive the awakened witch into various forms of homicidal madness or sociopathy. Trained hunters, craft-users or "seeds" themselves that have not become full witches, are needed to keep watch over "seeds" and hunt those whose abilities become active, serving in secret organizations, such as the parent branch "Solomon" and the "STN-J" branch in Japan, as self-appointed witch police to curtail the use of witchcraft in society, and to keep the witch kind a secret from the public. Even the police, who cooperate with STN-J in abnormal criminal cases, do not know what STN-J does.
>   The series begins when Robin arrives in Japan to gain information for Solomon headquarters about a fabled item that holds the "secrets of the craft," while acting undercover as a new hunter to the STN-J in their efforts to capture witches.

[image]

Robin Sena  is a soft-spoken 15-year-old Hunter with pyrokinetic abilities.

[image]

Above is a picture of Amon with a vial of Orbo.

> "Orbo" is a green liquid that negates witch abilities. STN-J's hunters
>   carry small vials of it on necklaces in the shape of a cross as a form
>   of protection against their targets' craft. Hunters also carry air
>   pistols which fire darts or pellets of Orbo that dampen witch powers
>   when it enters the bloodstream of the target witch.

[image]

Everybody wears fairly dark colors.

However Witch hunter Robin came out in 2002, not in the 90's and the organisation hunts only witches (male or female), no monsters.